# I want ASP.NET to list a Bool data type, true or false, in the table male if true and female if false

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I try to make patients table. I pulled the data from the database with entityframework. But I want to make the gender data male if true then female if false

aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using DentistAppointmentSystem.Entity;
namespace DentistAppointmentSystem.AdminPages
{
    public partial class DPatients : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        DentistAppointmentSystemEntities db = new DentistAppointmentSystemEntities();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var hastalar = (from x in db.TBL_PATIENTS
                            select new
                            {
                                x.TBL_USERS.Name,
                                x.TBL_USERS.Surname,
                                x.IDNumber,
                                x.Gender,
                                x.Birthday,
                                x.Phone
                            }).ToList();
            Repeater1.DataSource = hastalar;
            Repeater1.DataBind();

        }
    }
}
```

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFFjs.png)

I pulled the data from the database with entityframework. But I want to make the gender data male if true then female if false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this change within your anonymous projection.

```
var hastalar = (from x in db.TBL_PATIENTS
                            select new
                            {
                                x.TBL_USERS.Name,
                                x.TBL_USERS.Surname,
                                x.IDNumber,
                                Gender = x.Gender ? "Male" : "Female",
                                x.Birthday,
                                x.Phone
                            }).ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also make a function :

```
    public string GetGender(bool gender)
    {
        if (gender)
        {
            return "Male";
        }
        else
        {
            return "Female";
        }
    }
```

and then call it like:

x.Gender = GetGender(x.Gender)

Comment: This will most likely not work as EF will not be able to convert this to SQL.